# Helper Functions not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to use 2 helper functions for a function. Output is not showing any error but the output is showing the function syntax instead of return value

```
        function cuboidlwsidesSurfaceArea(length,width,height) {
            return 2*length*width
        }    
        function cuboidwhsidesSurfaceArea(length,width,height) {
            return cuboidlwsidesSurfaceArea(length,width,height) + 2*width*height
        }
        function cuboidsurfaceArea(length,width,height) {
            return cuboidwhsidesSurfaceArea(length,width,height) +2*length*height
        }
        document.write = cuboidsurfaceArea(10,5,20)
    </script>
```

Comment: This is impossible to read. Can you please spend some time writing a clearer question and formating your code so that it's legible? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write = cuboidsurfaceArea(10,5,20)
```

[document.write is a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write). Call it as such.

```
document.write(cuboidsurfaceArea(10,5,20));
```

If you want the value returned somewhere, assign it to a variable or return it from a function. Append it to a DOM element. You need to be specific about the use case if you want additional help on what to do with it.

Comment: Thanks! It was very silly from me. I'm New to Javascript and programming and is confused between functions, methods, properties, etc.

Comment: How can I return the value from a function. I mean the function returns the value to caller and in that case the function itself would be the caller. Who would the value be returned to?

Comment: That depends. Where are you calling the function FROM? Functions have callers. If you don't need a caller and are just trying to append something to an element, you can just invoke it from a script tag. Like, what are width and height? You don't have a full example of what you're trying to do, so it's hard to help.

Comment: Someone gave me this answer :                                                    document.write(function () { return cuboidsurfaceArea(10, 5, 20) } ).                                                                                    Now my only question is the function used here is the caller of cuboidsurfaceArea() function, so to whom the function is returning the value?